# Material for simple explanations of philosophies

Tags: reference-request

I am preparing for an examination which requires to have a general understanding of philosophies of certain Western thinkers (I have a hard time understanding Kant, Russell, Wittgenstein in particular).

The Wikipedia and other encyclopedias have material but there is no context or explanation of terms, which makes it a tough read.

Please share any resources which would explain these philosophers with some context and in general terms.

Comment: You can read the correspongin entries into [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/contents.html).

Comment: Otherwise, some History of Phil, like e.g. [Kenny's one](https://books.google.it/books?id=PgZrpNeulMMC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: All the philosophers you mention have volumes in the Oxford 'Very Short Introductions' series - brief, scholarly and clear. There's also Roger Scruton's 'Modern Philosophy' (1994).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one to be of great help. They have the summary, context and terms just as I wanted it and are a great help for a beginner -

http://www.sparknotes.com/philosophy/tractatus/